# Hadoop JobClient.getQueues() doesn't show Fair Scheduler pools

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Calling the getQueues() method of the JobClient class only seems to return the "default" queue, even though other pools have been created by the Fair Scheduler and have running jobs.  I wondered if I had a conceptual mismatch between "pools" and "queues", however calling the getJobsFromQueue() method for a non-default pool seems to work quite happily.

Is there a programmatic way of fetching the names of the queues (or pools?) from the Fair Scheduler using the JobClient class?  Or something else?

I should add that I'm using Hadoop 2.0.0 MR1 on Cloudera cdh4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to explicitly name the Fair Scheduler pools as queues using the mapred.queue.names property in the mapred site config file.